# Display Notification on Sms Receiving

Tags: android, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have made a `NotificationView` Class to display notification on receiving `SMS` which works fine but when I click on `Notification` the it does not clean and the Notification icon remain on Notification Bar but I wish to clean it pl specifies me some hints or sample code for that thanks in advance or sorry for if query is not get cleared..I tag the code

Thanks

The `displayNotification` method on `OnReceive` of `BroadcastReceiver`

```
private void displayNotification(String msg){
    Intent i = new Intent(this.context,NotificationView.class);
    i.putExtra("ID", ID);
    /*i.putExtra("msg",msg);*/
    PendingIntent pendInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, 0);
    Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.notify,"Receiving SMS",System.currentTimeMillis());
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, "SMS", msg, pendInt);
    notif.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
    notif.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notif.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;       
    notif.ledARGB = Color.WHITE;                         
    notif.ledOnMS = 1500;                         
    notif.ledOffMS = 1500;      
    nm.notify(ID, notif);
}
```

And this is the code for NotificationView class.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notificationview);
    txtNotify = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtNotification);
    ID = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("ID");
    /*txtNotify.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("msg"));*/
}

private View.OnClickListener txtClick = new View.OnClickListener() {    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.txtNotification:
            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            txtNotify.setText("");              
            nm.cancel(ID);          
            nm.cancelAll();
            NotificationView.this.startActivity(new Intent(NotificationView.this,ZigbeeActivity.class));
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are using pipe ("|") in below code

```
notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

remove it and check

```
notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Comment: sir I wish to apply default notification that u select from device sir please tell how I can set Default like Show_Light,Vibrate and Sound to notification